# IIS EventLog Errors

Tags: iis, iis-6, windows-event-log, eventviewer

I keep getting this error in my event viewer on IIS 6. I'm trying to figure out if my error resets my connection (maybe recycles the worker processes?).

The error is:

```
An attempt was made to load filter 'C:\Program Files\Software Artisans\FileUp
\FileUpIsapi.dll' but it requires the SF_NOTIFY_READ_RAW_DATA filter notification and 
this notification is not supported in Worker Process Isolation Mode.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink
/events.asp.
```

Comment: Can you check IUSR has read/write to that folder?  Sounds like a permissioning issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your ISAPI filter is not compatible with IIS6 Worker Process Isolation Mode. It sounds like it was written for IIS5.x.

For more information see this Microsoft KB article:

> [Information about ISAPI filters that register the SF_NOTIFY_READ_RAW_DATA event in Internet Information Services version 6.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311852)